# C# Entity sort search result by number of matching items

Tags: c#, search, entity

I am using this line of code to retrieve all recipes which have one or more matching ingredients

```
recipes = db.Recipes.Where(r => r.Ingredients.Any(i => FilteredsearchString.Contains(i.Ingredi‌​entName)));
```

The problem is that this sort the retrieved results by the number of matches. So if I look for 10 ingredients it can return a recipe that has only one of them prior to the one that has exactly those 10.

How do I make it return the recipes which have the most matched ingredients in them in descending order ?

The filtered search string is a string containing ingredient names separated by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it yet, but may be you could try the following:

```
var recipes = db.Recipes.Where(r => r.Ingredients
    .Any(i => FilteredsearchString.Contains(i.Ingredi‌​entName)))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Ingredients
        .Count(y => FilteredsearchString.Contains(y.IngredientName));
```

Comment: It works very well, thank you very much for the quick reply!